# Two div next to each other, with full width

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following:

column A, be as width as the maximum listitem | column B, be as width as place left, with having horizontal scrollbox when overleaps.

WIDTH:auto | WIDTH: 100%;

```
list1   | adklajd lkasjdlk ajs kldajlkjd kalsd 
list222 | sdfsf
list33  | sdfsdffds
        | xxx
```

how to do this? Its not even easy.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3p9F/
and column B goes to new line, I dont want it

Comment: Um... what? Not sure what you are asking.  Please use jsfiddle.

Comment: Why would you get a horizontal scrollbar? Is the `div` constrained to a particular height?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a combination of `float` and `margin` to achieve this:

```
<div id="colA">
    <!-- completely irrelevant mark-up -->
</div>
<div id="colB">
    <p><!-- Completely irrelevant text... --></p>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
#colA {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 100%; /* to prevent the #colB text wrapping beneath #colA */
}

#colB {
    clear: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7nyY7/).

(Tested only in Chromium 22/Ubuntu 12.10.)

Comment: Yeah, the down-side is that the `margin-bottom` extends for `100%` of its parent element, though. If `#colA` and `#colB` are contained *within* another element, though, it'll extend only within that container element, though. =/

Answer (score 3):

Hmm

Two parts to this

1. HTML
2. CSS for file

HTML

```
<html>
 <div id='col1'> </div>
 <div id='col2'> </div>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#col1 {
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}
#col2 {
 float: left;
 clear: right;
 width: 100%;
}
```

**Explanation**
Float basically aligns the divs to the left of the viewport (or screen) and clear removes any floating items from the right side of the second column.

This in combination with setting at 100% ensures that your two divs are next to each other and that the first one is only as wide as it needs to be and the second one fills up the rest of the space to the right of the first column.

Comment: and how to reverse this? if col1 should take all the space it can get an col2 only 200px or so?